# mailto: problem

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm trying to set up the following mailto: link:

```
<a href='mailto:info@example.com?subject=Testing&body=http://www.google.com?foo=1&bar=2'>Send mail</a>
```

However the second argument (bar) is cut off because it is seen as an argument of the mailto link and not the link I'm putting in the body. I tried `&amp;` but it does the same thing since it's being rendered into the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
<a href='mailto:info@example.com?subject=Testing&amp;body=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Ffoo%3D1%26bar%3D2'>Send mail</a>
```

ie, [urlencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the whole `body` field, to make sure nothing causes any problem ?

Comment: +1 remembering to &-escape the ampersand in the link. However note that either way, mailto: link parameters like ‘subject’ and ‘body’ are non-standard and not compatible with every mailer so shouldn't be relied on.

Answer (score 2):

Use "%26" instead or use urluncoding like suggested in another answer.  For PHP [rawurlencode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) works well.

```
<a href='mailto:info@example.com?subject=Testing&body=http://www.google.com?foo=1%26bar=2'>Send mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the value for body into quotes like:

```
'mailto:info@example.com?subject=Testing&body="http://www.google.com?foo=1&bar=2"'
```

Nvm, turns out putting %26 works instead of ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Use %26 as &.. its the html escape code for &.

`<a href='mailto:info@example.com?subject=Testing&body=http://www.google.com?foo=1%26bar=2'>Send mail</a>`